# Referencing different libraries depending on the architecture in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to add to my C# project a reference to a different dll versions in x86 and x64 (and switch automatically between them, while changing Configuration Mode)?

Comment: Is there any more info you can provide about the target references?  Any reason why they weren't build for 'Any CPU', are they 3rd party assemblies, do you want this for debugging or just for your deployment?

Comment: this might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @Steve Danner: They are 3rd party assemblies. Actually, this is necessary for both debugging and release builds.

Comment: @DK: Well, possibly what you provided could be a solution. Still, I'd prefer a build-time resolution of the required assembly. This feature is accessible in C++ projects.

Comment: @rook: sry, for some reason I also believed you were thinking about run-time, same as Dykam :). User's solution looks great. I believe conditional compilation can be used as well, but it's way much more mess in this case.

Comment: @DK: No problem, actually what you said at first is quite reasonable. I'd guess that dynamically choosing between x86/x64 assemblies may allow to compile for 'Any CPU' and help to get rid of two separate deployment packages for customers. However, in my case this approach seems to cause runtime errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's anything in the IDE that will do this, but you can accomplish this by manually editing the C# project file.

Something that looks like: `<Reference Include="ThirdPartyAssembly" />`

Could be changed to:
`<Reference Include="ThirdPartyAssembly.x86" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'" />`
`<Reference Include="ThirdPartyAssembly.x64" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'" />`

Comment: That is entirely compile time, he needs it most probably at runtime.

Comment: @Dykam: I thought it was pretty clear in the original question that rook wanted a compile time solution.

Comment: Somehow I read "change Configuration Mode" as runtime mode... I take it back.

Comment: Works as a charm, thanks! In fact both dlls appear in the 'References' section in the Solution Explorer, but only one is loaded. Another is shown as if it was unresolved. It works fine, though.

Comment: Even more compact would be <Reference Include="ThirdPartyAssembly.$(Platform)" />